# ORDER BY a truth value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all items that have a percentage value greater than 90%, but the ordering of that part doesn't matter. Here's an example:

```
Person    Score    Location
1           91       US
2           92       CA
3           89       US
4           99       CA
```

I want to order it by (1) whether the score is > 90, and then (2) the location str. Here's how it should turn out:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'score is > 90', location
```

And the results would then be:

```
Person    Score    Location
4           92       AL
2           92       CA
1           99       US
3           89       US
```

Note that I do not want to do the question `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score, location`.

How would I actually do this ordering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically just remove the single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY (score > 90) DESC, location;
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the usage of the `IS` keyword before the comparison operator. That's new to me. This is the right approach, a boolean expression evaluates to 1 (true), 0 (false) or NULL.

Comment: Basically just remove the single quotes **and** the `is` word :-)